# Положение картинки по центру окна

Tags: qt5, qml

Имеется qml окно, в нем необходимо по центру расположить картинку и добавить возможность передвигать эту картинку мышкой (в идеале хотелось бы двигать только картинку, которая не помещается в окне, а маленькую запретить двигать). Для добавления возможности двигать использую блок `Flickable`. Возникает следующая проблема: картинка, которая больше окна  располагается корректно по центру окна, а маленькая картинка сдвигается в начало координат. Подскажите, что я делаю не правильно.

PS: нигде не нашел примера, как добавить условие на возможность двигать.

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
Window {
id: win
visible: true
width: 1000; height: 1000

 Flickable
 {
    clip : true
    width: 1000; height: 1000
    anchors.fill: parent
    contentHeight: myIcon.height
    contentWidth: myIcon.width
    //contentX: myIcon.width < width ? width / 2 - myIcon.width / 2 :myIcon.width / 2 - width / 2
    //contentY: myIcon.height < height ? height / 2 - myIcon.height / 2 :myIcon.height / 2 - height / 2
    contentX: myIcon.width / 2 - width / 2
    contentY: myIcon.height / 2 - height / 2
    Image
    {
        id: myIcon
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        source: "1.jpg"
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видимо,

```
anchors.centerIn: parent
```

не работает, если родитель `Flickable` или работает не так, как хочется по причине того, что необходимо центровать картинку не в `Flickable`, а в его контенте. Первое, что приходит на ум - сделать промежуточный `Item`, который будет контентом для `Flickable`. Примерно так:

```
 Flickable
 {
    anchors.fill: parent
    contentHeight: idContent.height
    contentWidth: idContent.width
    Item {
        id: idContent
        width: math.max(1000, myIcon.width)
        height: math.max(1000, myIcon.height)
        Image
        {
            id: myIcon
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            source: "1.jpg"
        }
    }
 }
```

Или можно использовать свойства `leftMargin` и `rightMargin` для центровки маленькой картинки.

Свойство Flicable включающее возможность двигать - interactive.